# How to apply matched filter over surface of image instead of lines on 2d matrix: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, signal-processing

I have a 2d matrix and want to implement a matched filter on this matrix(image) of size 360x360

a=360x360

I tried to read about the matched filter but still unsure about it?

**MY ATTEMPT**(But this is not desired as this makes matched filter over lines and not on my image)

```
img=a;
s = 1.5; %sigma
L = 7;
theta = 0:15:165; 
out = zeros(size(img));
m = max(ceil(3*s),(L-1)/2);
[x,y] = meshgrid(-m:m,-m:m);
for t = theta
   t = t / 180 * pi;        
   u = cos(t)*x - sin(t)*y; 
   v = sin(t)*x + cos(t)*y; 
   N = (abs(u) <= 3*s) & (abs(v) <= L/2); 
   k = exp(-u.^2/(2*s.^2)); 
   k = k - mean(k(N));
   k(~N) = 0;              
   res = conv2(img,k,'same');
   out = max(out,res);
end
imagesc(out)
```

My expectation was to get a more clear and bright image but I didn't get that

My expectation was to get a more clear and bright image of this coin but I didn't get that

I want to reduce noise and get a better image

I want to reduce noise and apply over image surface, not on lines get a better image

Comment: Why do you say it’s not accurate? What is your output, and what output do you expect? What feature is your filter supposed to match? Which particular version of a matched filter are you trying to implement?

Comment: I have added @CrisLuengo details

Comment: Just a simple matched filter I want to implement over this image

Comment: I want to reduce the noise and get a better image whereas this made it more noisy

Comment: A matched filter is meant to match specific features in the mage, to detect where those features happen. I think you implemented a matched filter for lines, and so are detecting lines. If you want to reduce noise and improve the image clarity, you could try for example a bilateral filter, which is one of the many options for edge-preserving smoothing filters.

Comment: can you help! regarding matched filter over the surface or with bilateral filter

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bilateral+filter+matlab

Comment: Is matched filter applied only on lines?

Comment: Matched filters are to detect specific shapes. Typically lines, but could be other shapes too.